# C# Best way to avoid duplicate per time slot in log file

Tags: c#, file, logging, io

I have a simple stand-alone logging app based on C# code, it takes the parameters and append them into the log file.

Some events showed up in the log multiple time (due to retries)

What will be the best way to "skip" logging repeated events for x period of time?

(Since the logging app is only invoked when event happened I cannot keep this data in memory)

My first thought is to keep some sort of a file with hashes of the events (excluding time stamp) and check it in a list, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do so, since we are logging quite a lot of data and I'm afraid that managing another file, running the hash function and search my be a killer for the functionality.

Comment: The functionality you are describing exceeds a simple log file mechanism. You should try `SQLite` and do the logging there. A double column index on `"log_message", "log_timestamp"` will give you the ability to query for messages that starts with `Whatever error message` for the last X minutes and if nothing found, `INSERT .....`

Answer (score 0):

The logger really shouldn't be editing what is written since it doesn't (or at least shouldn't) know about business logic -- such as retries.

If you don't want each retry logged, move the logging up a level in the code so it only logs after all retries fail.

For instance, it sounds like you have something like this (pseudo-code)

```
loop retries x number of times
    try action
    did action succeed?
        yes: break out of loop
        no : increment x
             log failure
end of retry loop
... logic continues
```

when what you actually want is

```
set success flag to false
loop retries x number of times
    try action
    did action succeed?
        yes: set success flag to true
             break out of loop
        no : increment x
end of while
is success flag true
    yes: continue
    no : log failure
... logic continues
```

The difference is just to move the logging out of the retry loop.

Comment: I can only control the logging app code, I cannot change the code of the app that invokes the logger